# Unable to Install Ubuntu 12.04 on my windows 7 hp Laptop Dvd Ejects automatically

Tags: 12.04

Hi I am very new to Ubuntu and but i want it.

I downloaded Ubuntu Iso file from the site and burnt the image to a Dvd. 
I boot my Windows 7 laptop using the dvd, the Screen shows all the options and then when i select "Install Ubuntu along with Windows 7" , it takes a while and then the Dvd gets ejected "Eject the media and Press Enter " and the system reboots into windows 7.

Can any one help me to sort this out. Note : I use a USB dongle for Internet and dont have any wifi around. So there is no internet connectivity during installation. Pls find below my Laptop configuration.

```
Genuine Windows 7 Home Premium 32-bit
15.6” inch (1366×768 pixels) HP LED Brightview Display
AMD Athlon II M300 Dual-Core Processor (2.0 GHz, 1 MB L2 Cache)
ATI Radeon 3200 Integrated Graphics
4GB DDR2 RAM
320 GB Hard Disk
8X DVD±RW with Double Layer Support
5-in-1 integrated Memory Card Reader
High speed 56K modem
WLAN 802.11b/g
Bluetooth
Integrated Fingerprint reader
Webcam with Integrated MIc
Altec Lansing speakers
65 W AC Power Adapter
6 cell battery
Weight: 2.94 Kg
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the DVD that you burned did not burn correctly, or the ISO file you downloaded is corrupted.

I suggest you make a bootable USB disk with Ubnutu using the following link and try to install from it http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Tell us how it goes.